# Line height for title changes in post revisions is too small

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Behold below.  The problem only occurs when the title changes but not the body.  Example title changes on [this post, revs 2 and 5](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/1869/revisions) render poorly, but title+body changes on [this one, rev 3](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/21409/revisions) seem fine.

[image]

Using Chrome 34 on Windows 7 SP1 x64. 100% (no) zoom.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed. It will be live after our next production build.